# How to combine .htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, web

I want to combine these two `.htaccess` rules for a website:

```
RewriteRule ^newsletter\.html$ https://fleio.com/newsletter [L,R=301]  
RewriteRule ^newsletter[/]?$ newsletter.html [L]
```

If only one is active, it is doing what it has to do. But when I use both of them I get an error

> too many redirects.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M6rYkEV-tmO7wRSJYjGtGOFow-76ZvbODnnjiqCh1m0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You're redirecting one to the other and vice versa, that's a loop. Which URLs do you want to redirect where?

Comment: we don't go "outside" to look at code. paste it here as an edit to your question

Comment: RewriteRule ^newsletter\.html$ https://exanple.com/newsletter [L,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^newsletter[/]?$ newsletter.html [L]

Comment: I want that newsletter to show the content of newsletter.html and after that newsletter.html to be redirected to  example.com/newsletter

Comment: that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Yes, but if both rules are active I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" so I want to remove somehow that loop, or try other rules.

Comment: OP, I can't view the Google document in this question (something to do with cookies). Please replace it with the text you wanted to show here, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second rule is internally redirecting the request to same location (The first rue) multiple time so you are getting the loop error. You need to use a RewriteCond and match against the_request variable to prevent the rewrite loop.

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /newsletter\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newsletter/ [L,R]
RewriteRule ^newsletter/?$ /newsletter.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you starkeen ! Work's just fine.

Comment: You are welcome @badrhari If you are on apache  `2.4.`
you can use the **END** 
 flag in your internal rewriteRule to prevent the rewrite loop.






The following example works on apache 2.4 and later :


`RewriteRule ^newsletter\.html$ https://fleio.com/newsletter [L,R=301]  
 RewriteRule ^newsletter[/]?$ newsletter.html [END]`